# ee3 install - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in admin.php on line 80

Tags: install

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. Why would I be the only person with this error? Like 80 says:

```
$system_path = $system_path ?: __DIR__;
```

Looks weird, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Requirements say PHP 5.3.10 or newer. Server is only 5.2.17.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,  Syntax error line 80   I asked my hoster to install latest version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue here, running PHP 5.4 with Expression Engine 3.5.14

Checked my error logs and found this:

[05-Jan-2018 16:55:49] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in /my_root/public_html/admin.php on line 80

Anyone?